# Why does FFT not work from the context menu when drawing multiple plots?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I've been trying to find a way to draw multiple plots and their respective Y axes. All the plots should share a time x axis.

I've been mostly successful except that applying a transform from the context menu seems to only work on the first plot which is created in the initial plot item.

For example, the FFT is only applied to the first plot and not the others, why might that be?

Here's my code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultiplePlotAxes')
p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.setLabels(left='axis 1')

## create a new ViewBox, link the right axis to its coordinate system
p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.scene().addItem(p2)
p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p1.vb)
p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('axis2', color='#0000ff')

## create third ViewBox. 
## this time we need to create a new axis as well.
p3 = pg.ViewBox()
ax3 = pg.AxisItem('right')
p1.layout.addItem(ax3, 2, 3)
p1.scene().addItem(p3)
ax3.linkToView(p3)
p3.setXLink(p1.vb)
ax3.setZValue(-10000)
ax3.setLabel('axis 3', color='#ff0000')

## Handle view resizing 
def updateViews():
    ## view has resized; update auxiliary views to match
    global p1, p2, p3
    p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p3.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())

    ## need to re-update linked axes since this was called
    ## incorrectly while views had different shapes.
    ## (probably this should be handled in ViewBox.resizeEvent)
    p2.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p2.XAxis)
    p3.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p3.XAxis)

updateViews()
p1.vb.sigResized.connect(updateViews)

time = np.zeros(6)
sampleRate = 10
time = (np.arange(len(time))*1/sampleRate) - 0.001
## Add data to the plots
data1 = np.array([1,2,4,8,16,32])
data2 = np.array([10,20,40,80,40,20])
data3 = np.array([3200,1600,800,400,200,100])

plot1 = p1.plot(time, data1)
plot2 = pg.PlotDataItem(time, data2, pen='b')
p2.addItem(plot2)
plot3 = pg.PlotDataItem(time, data3, pen='r')
p3.addItem(plot3)

## Set the scales of the views to fit the data
p1.enableAutoRange(axis='y')
p2.enableAutoRange(axis='y')
p3.enableAutoRange(axis='y')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

It seems that it works when I do not introduce an x axis parameter to the plot function as follows:

```
plot1 = p1.plot(data1)
plot2 = pg.PlotDataItem(data2, pen='b')
p2.addItem(plot2)
plot3 = pg.PlotDataItem(data3, pen='r')
p3.addItem(plot3)
```

But this is worthless for my purposes since I need a time axis that corresponds to specific XY values.